# Weird reflections in smooth shading, which cease to exist in edit mode

Tags: shaders, smooth

I am trying to model a spaceship for my mod, and I usually fix the weird smooth by just extruding without moving the extrusion. Sometimes it works well, but sometimes errors like now occur.
On the left side weird shading have been fully fixed by aforementioned method [image: good shading]

On the right side, however it seems to work outright bad and very distorted [image: cringy shading]

But the weirdest part, is that this problem totally ceases to occur when the model is viewed in edit mode[image: cringy shading gone when edit mode is turned on]

This is not the first time this happens. I will send the blend file if requested

Comment: Hello and welcome, it could be face orientation

Comment: 'extruding without moving the extrusion' will result in coincident geometry, which is generally a Bad Thing. Could you just split the normals (Autiosmooth)  and mark the edges you don't want interpolated as sharp?

Comment: Turned out it was due to face orientation, thanks Emir for answering